# Filter out ambiguous bases from a DNA sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, bioinformatics

I have this function:

```py
import re

def check_and_clean_sequence(sequence, alphabet):
    """
    Function to check and clean up all ambiguous bases in a sequence.
    Ambigous bases are bases that are not in the sequence
    alphabet, ie. 'ACGT' for DNA sequences.
    
    Inputs:
    
        sequence - a string representing a DNA sequence.
        alphabet - set/string representing the allowed
                   characters in a sequence.
    
    Outputs:
    
        cleaned_sequence - cleaned sequence or a string.
    """    
    if set(sequence).issubset(alphabet):
        return sequence
    else:
        return cleaning_ambiguous_bases(sequence)


def cleaning_ambiguous_bases(sequence):
    """
    Function to clean up all ambiguous bases in a sequence.
    Ambiguous bases are bases that are not in the sequence
    alphabet, ie. 'ACGT' for DNA sequences.
    
    Inputs:
    
        sequence - a string representing a DNA sequence.
    
    Outputs:
    
        integer - a new clean up string representing a DNA sequence
                  without any ambiguous characteres.
    """
    # compile the regex with all ambiguous bases
    pat = re.compile(r'[NRYWXSKM]')
    # look for the ambiguous bases and replace by
    # nothing
    new_seq = re.sub(pat,  '',    sequence)
    return new_seq
```

The performance in jupyter notebook with timeit is around:

```
%timeit check_and_clean_sequence(seq, iupac_dna)
200 ms ± 436 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

This was calculated with a DNA sequence with 5539776 pb or 5539.776 kpb. The sequence can be downloaded from:
[E. coli genome](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/005/845/GCF_000005845.2_ASM584v2/GCF_000005845.2_ASM584v2_genomic.fna.gz)

The function receive a big string and check if there are any characters that
are not in the allowed alphabet (in the case the IUPAC DNA = 'ACGT').
If the sequence has they are cleaned up and the function returns a new sequence,
otherwise return the original one.

Are there are tips or tricks to improve this time?

Toy example:

```
>>> import re
>>> alphabet = 'ACGT'
>>> toy_sequence = 'AGCTAGGGACATTGAGGACCACCACAXYXMAAAAAA'
>>> check_and_clean_sequence(toy_sequence, alphabet)
'AGCTAGGGACATTGAGGACCACCACAAAAAAA'
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: Like I said before - please stop modifying (including adding) code in your post. If you have an updated version then you can create a new post and [edit] to add a link to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the bioinformatics side, not the python one: Your return will be non-useful for further processing whenever an ambiguous base has been present, because it changes index locations! You'll want to fix that before worrying about how long it takes to run...

DNA and RNA are themselves a form of coding language: three base units ('codons') describe amino acids. Whenever a base is deleted, a 'frameshift' occurs: every codon after that point now starts a space sooner than it should. (In vivo, a single frameshift mutation is usually sufficient to completely shut off one - or more! - genes. In other words, this is not a trivial situation.) **You cannot *interpret* genetic sequences correctly if you change the index location of the bases!**

There are three paths to usefully 'cleaning' your genome information, depending on why you wanted to do that in the first place:

1. If space is at a premium:

   Drawing from Kraigolas: use the code as described, but rather than replacing with the empty string, replace with a uniform "this base is ambiguous" marker, thus maintaining index locations. ('N' is the standard for this specific application.)

   ```
    pattern = re.compile(r"[^ACGT]")
    print(pattern.sub("N", toy_sequence))
   ```

   Another solution in this vein is to store bases as tuples of (index [type:int], base type [could handle a number of ways]) but this is probably space-inefficient
2. If neither space nor preprocessing are an optimization concern: Don't do any deletion or substitution of these characters at all.

   Look at the documentation related to the source of your sequences; there will either be an interpretation key for their specific method [or they'll be using the standard lookup table](https://genomevolution.org/wiki/index.php/Ambiguous_nucleotide).
   When a subsequent step will be to interpret a sequence into an amino acid string (likely application) or to look for "similar" sequences in a database (also a likely application), knowing the difference between the code that means "either A or T" and the code that means "either C or G" will *save* you processing time and/or get less ambiguous *results*.
3. If preprocessing is a concern:

   As in 2, refer to the appropriate [lookup table](https://genomevolution.org/wiki/index.php/Ambiguous_nucleotide) for what ambiguous codes mean.
   Read your sequence into a [length of sequence]x4 array of binary values.
   Column 1 is "can be A?", column 2 is "can be T?", etc. -

   Example: AGCCNCS would become

   ```
    1  0  0  0
    0  0  1  0
    0  0  0  1
    0  0  0  1
    1  1  1  1
    0  0  0  1
    0  0  1  1
   ```

   As appropriate codon matches (there are almost always more than one) for specific amino acids can be easily described in the same way, it's relatively trivial to use this format for a variety of purposes, and it removes assorted other headaches with accurately interpreting the ambiguous codes.

   (For examples of how to apply them - treating the bin as if they're integers, if the dot product of each row in two sequence matrixes is at least 1, you have a 'match' of codes!)

Comment: Man you totally right I just having a hard time coding this kmers count functions efficiently. I know there are a lot of tools out there but I am learning python them I need to code to learn! Then I am write my own code! But some times some obvious details get out of control. Thanks to you I avoid a big mistake. Thank you a lot. I will go back to basics and use something like if set(kmer).issubset(set(alphabet)) to avoid ambiguous kmers in the final counts. This way I will keep all the indexes corrects. Thank you a lot! Its better a slow and correct code than a quick and wrong one. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps there aren't enough test cases here, because I don't see why you can't just use:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[^ACGT]")
print(pattern.sub("", toy_sequence))
```

Which says replace all characters that are not in `ACGT` with blanks. Thus, you do not need to know which characters are illegal, only those which are legal. This should be very fast, doesn't require a function definition because compiling `pattern` really serves as your function, which you now call with `pattern.sub`, and is a lot easier to read.

## Redundant functions

If this is a satisfactory answer, I'd like to say that

```
def check_and_clean_sequence(sequence, alphabet):
```

is not a valuable function even if my solution did not work. `cleaning_ambiguous_bases` will achieve the same result and it will not be any slower. Checking first will at *best* perform the same as just calling `cleaning_ambiguous_bases` because regardless, you need to check every character. However, if you check first, you will iterate through the sequence potentially twice: once to check, and then once to replace. It's faster to just walk through once.

Comment: when you get so involved in coding that sometimes this kind of redundancy escape from the eyes...Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PauloSergioSchlogl Don't worry about it! It's happened to all of us before, that's why we're here. Glad I could help :)

Comment: @PauloSergioSchlogl: I did some testing with sequences that don't need cleaning, e.g. `"AGCTAGGGACATTGAGGACCACCACAAAAAAAAGCTAGGGACATTGAGGACCACCACAAAAAAA"`. With this string, `check_and_clean_sequence()` is twice as fast as `cleaning_ambiguous_bases()` on my system (it is still slower than the suggested `pattern.sub()` solution, though). The reason for this is that turning the string into a set greatly reduces the comparisons that need to be made. I'd argue, then, that we can't just assume that the check is redundant as it depends on the length and the messiness of the input.

Answer (score 8):

There's an inconsistency between the two functions.  `check_and_clean_sequence()` has an `alphabet` parameter, but this isn't used by the inner function, which has a hard-coded list of invalid characters to remove.

The `check_and_clean_sequence()` function doesn't add value - all it does is add overhead of an extra pass through the string (`re.sub()` will just do a single pass and return the original string if there's nothing to change).

In the docstrings, there are many (different!) misspellings of the word "ambiguous".  I know it's not an easy word for a non-native speaker, but it shouldn't be hard to fix those.

You could possibly use `filter()` to keep only the characters in `alphabet`, but my guess is that it's unlikely to beat `re` for speed.  `re.compile()` creates a simple, fast, DFA (discrete finite automaton) that's highly optimised for matching.  The best improvement you could make is to compile the regex just once, rather than every call.  And then as Kraigolas suggest, replace the function call with a simple `pattern.sub()` (I guess you could bind the empty-string first argument, to get a function that accepts just the sequence).

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! I will check for the misspellings! 8)